# For ever and forever

Tags: meaning, adverbs, british-english

What is the difference between the meaning and usage of *for ever* and *forever* in British English? From what I could gather from my online research,

> *forever* means :
>
> 1. (also for ever) for all future time; for always
> 2. continually

and

> *for ever* - Oxford has only Eng-Ger, Eng-It and Eng-Sp entries for it(apart from being redirected to forever's definition), Collins says it is an adverb meaning *forever*.

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/114420/40336

Comment: @Jerry: ELU questions which are closed as "general reference" and have no answers on the ELU question are **not** duplicates when posted here.

Answer (score 2):

In short, there is very little difference, if any, and I wouldn't worry about it. Only as a noun ( e.g. *until forever*) should it always be written as *forever*.

---

The Oxford English Dictionary says:

> **Ever:**
>
> 5b: in phrases, *for ever* (sometimes, esp. in U.S., written *forever*, q.v.)
>
> **Forever (adverb):**
>
> 1. The phrase *for ever* (see ever 5b), written as one word. Chiefly U.S. exc. in sense ‘incessantly’.
> 2. quasi-n. *Eternity, perpetuity.*

I think most readers wouldn't even notice whether you used one spelling or the other. But the OED indicates some subtle, potential differences: it is spelled *for ever* everywhere and in all senses, but the spelling *forever* for the adverb is more common in America, whereas in England *forever* is more likely to mean "incessantly", so in a sentence that describes a repeated action. As a noun, it is always *forever*.

Comment: The Q. relates specifically to BrE while the citations refer to AmE use of the word in place of the phrase. The word and the phrase do not always mean the same in BrE.

Comment: @Kris can you please elaborate upon the differences?

Comment: @Kris: I have all the information available in the OED, which includes both British and American usage. I have interpreted and explained the OED in this regard, which includes explicit mention of the differences between British and American usage. What more is there to say? Do tell us if you have more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that forever and ever do have two different meanings. Ever, meaning at all times; continuously. Forever, with the prefix fore would suggest the meaning of "before" in space, time, condition. So forever would make one think of past eternity as opposed to a future eternity. So "Forever" is past & future eternity while "Ever" is future only eternity. So there is a difference between forever and everlasting

Comment: If you had ever considered this sentence you might not have written this :)